# Automatically log off and *close* Windows 10 user session

Tags: windows-10

My wife will leave the PC without logging off and then the machine will lock due to inactivity but not sign her off.  I also use this PC and sometimes need to dial in to a VPN that does not allow for other sessions running on the machine.  Is there a way to have Windows log off and *close* an inactive session (not just lock it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows won't log off a locked session on its own since it could result data loss so there is no such setting as far as I know. However you can order Windows to log off her disconnected session via the Task Manager. Select the Users tab, right click on the user in question and select Sign off. But you have to do this manually every time.

Comment: That will be good enough.  It's better than switching to her id and logging it off.  She only ever uses the machine for Facebook